# Getting max of an array in ASM

Tags: assembly, pic

I'm trying to get the max value of an array in asm but there is a problem with `CPFSGT` command: it is not definable, I don't know why. I'm using PIC16F877.

```
 CBLOCK
    MYARRAY : 0
             ARG00 EQU D'8' , ARG01 EQU D'9', ARG02 EQU D'2', ARG03 EQU D'1',
             ARG04 EQU D'7', ARG05 EQU D'5', ARG06 EQU D'4', ARG07 EQU D'6'
             ARG08 EQU D'0', ARG09 EQU D'3'
    ENDC

        Max EQU 0x73
        Counter EQU 0x74
        GOTO getMax

    getMax:
        MOVLW .0 
        MOVFW Max
        MOVLW .9
        MOVFW Counter
    loop:
        MOVLW MYARRAY + Counter
        CPFSGT Max
        MOVFW MaX
        DECFSZ Counter
        GOTO loop
        MOVLW MaX
```

Comment: http://wiki.4hv.org/index.php/Instruction_set:_PIC doesn't list `CPFSGT` as a supported instruction for PIC16, so you might have to use something like a `SUBWF` / `SKPC` combination instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are completely lost...

1. The `CPFSGT` instruction is supported only in PIC18 family and not
   in PIC16 as in your case.
2. Directive `CBLOCK` is intended to declare block constants and not
   program arrays.
3. Use `FSR0` or `FSR1` register as pointer to your array